# Django admin display specific model in form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm creating a project to make collective translations, so I got original text, with images. Basic idea is split text into chunks, chunks could be different types: text and images (images can be uploaded, alt and description could be edited...)

There is proof-of-concept

```
class Source(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class SourceChunk(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source)

class SourceTextChunk(models.Model):
    chunk = models.ForeignKey(SourceChunk)
    text = models.TextField()

class SourceImageChunk(models.Model):
    chunk = models.ForeignKey(SourceChunk)
    image = models.FileField()
    alt = models.TextField()
    title = models.TextField()
    transcription = models.TextField()

class SourceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

And I want to create form, using SourceAdmin (in admin page), which will be displayed this way:

```
... some other fields ...
text form
text form
text form
text form
image form
text form
text form
text form
```

Comment: did you have try to make some form to show us the code ?

Comment: I add some more information to quetion. I want to create admin form, as it generated by django.

Comment: [you can have a look at this official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial02/) which should help